# tcp\ip server tracking database changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, tcp

I have a tcp\server ( .NET 3.5 ) that notifies connected clients about aah interesting events. These events occur because an aspx website is writing stuff to a database( SQL 2005 )
What would be a good way for this server to monitor the database so to speak
can the db push info to the server in any way?

any suggestions thoughts welcome 
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at SQL Broker Service - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108(SQL.90).aspx.

To take this further you can use SqlDependency. There is a nice small article on CodeProject - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/chatter.aspx.

There are some caveats using it but many of them are already described on the web. Use the following resources:

1. http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2005/12/06/sqlcachedependency-hell.aspx
2. http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/04/29/2929.aspx

SQL Broker services is quite vast to get in details with, but I hope I gave you good resources to start up with.

Comment: um broker basically puts data from one table to another table?
or am I understanding it wrong
i need a running service\.exe to get notified when the db changes
thanks

Comment: What you need to look further is SqlDependency. I will update my answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Needed instant notification of data insertion. I used SQL Broker Service and CLR stored procedure (written in C#). The procedure notify about the inserted data to another application using socket.

You can write similar CLR stored proc or CLR Trigger (Offcource asynchronous when using service broker)